# APEX download files app for customer

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have theoretical question as I'm not familiar with `Oracle APEX` yet and I don't know if it's worth to start with my idea.

**case:**

- let's say I'll do everything locally on my machine (just to simplify this case)
- I have PL/SQL procedure which generates flat files into one of local folders (or on server in plans) i.e. `C:\rep_files\`

Now, I want to create apex app where client could log in, see the list of files in shared folder (like in windows explorer or total commander maybe or just as a list that he can chose from), browse one of them and download to his local machine.

I've found lot of articles with solutions like uploading files into database as BLOB and then downloading it - that is not a solution I'm looking for.

Did anyone try to do it that way? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

there can be different options for it.

in apex web page report, you can give href hyperlinks to rows

if i would be you,i would modify my pl/sql procedure for recording the file names and location to a table while it is generating files.

then at apex app i would prepare my report for the table and give hyperlink to each file location. then at click of hyperlink browser would download that file (like coding a file link in html)

but in this scenario files should be in a network share or folder should be at a web server depending on your architecture and it will need appropriate access rights, after click browser will handle the file

Comment: It seems resonable solution if I understand it well - did you try it before? Do you have any examples maybe?

Comment: i used similar logic for the images. instead of using database i upload the images to a web share and displayed it within application by storing the image locations in database

Comment: please check this https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=91610:1:106650513729594:::::

Comment: Thanks, it looks ok, but I need to try it myself during this week.

Comment: if you live problem sent me a message from here. i would sent you demo app in a way

Comment: Hi again @Bahadirs, could you tell me how exactly did you put your href link into table so it can be displayed as hyperlink i Apex table? I am trying lot of combinations here but it's going nowhere.

Comment: hi massko
i used all default paramaters with following table and code
i only changed donwloan colum from text to  "standard report column"


Table =
Column Name Data Type Nullable Default Primary Key
ID NUMBER No - 1
LOCATION VARCHAR2(256) Yes - -
NAME VARCHAR2(256) Yes - -


table sample data=
LOCATION NAME ID
 Edit https://www.dropbox.com/s/7y2kqfop8yf4kzs/test.rtf?dl=1 testfile 1
 
 
 report source=
 select ID,
       NAME,
       '<A href=' || LOCATION || '>download</A>' as download
  from DONWLOAD_TEST

Comment: Hi @Bahadirs, thanks for a quick answer. So you are creating this hyperlink by Apex interface with not putting it into table record before? Could you please send me some screenshots with step-by-step actions I think I don't get it please? skover000@gmail.com